# Cannot Join on @JoinColumn which is @Id

Tags: java, hibernate, join, hibernate-criteria

I have an @Entity class which has multiple ID columns and all of them are foreign key. The class code looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Immutable
@Table(name = "AnyNews")
public class AnyNews implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 43876852L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Id
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "news_id")
    private News news;

    .....
}
```

I want to add `Restriction` on `Criteria` with `News` Entity's `date` column. So I made criteria like this:

```
Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
        .createCriteria(AnyNews.class, "any")
        .createCriteria("news", "news");
        .add(Restrictions.eq("news.id", id))
        .add(Restrictions.ge("news.date", from.getTime()));
```

The code looks good but it makes error like:

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
...
```

The problem was caused because of missing Join statement. There was no Join statement on query:

```
select
    this_.id as news4_5_0_,
    this_.news_id as keyword1_5_0_,
    this_.board_no as board2_5_0_,
    this_.seq as seq5_0_ 
from
    AnyNews this_ 
where
    this_.news_id=? 
    and news1_.date>=?
```

Why does Hibernate makes query like this. Can't I use @Id and @JoinColumn annotation on same column?

Answer (score 0):

You need a `@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)` annotation to do that join.

Or, maybe do a  `.setFetchMode("news", FetchMode.JOIN)`